# Usage of apple Device check with firebase app check

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-app-check

I am looking at adding firebase check to my app but I was wondering what the quota for apples device check is. The docs say 'DeviceCheck access is subject to any quotas or limitations set by Apple.' but I cannot find any information about it on apples website

Does anyone have any knowledge on this topic? I can't even tell if it's an entirely free tool like the android SafetyNet is.

Thanks